# How to use Vaadin and Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin, hibernate-envers

I am having trouble figuring out how to use Hibernate Envers and Vaadin.  I have a vaadin web application which has tables of information which users can edit.  I am using a postgresql to store the data, and have used Hibernate to create the Bean classes (I have multiple Bean classes and multiple SQL tables) and linking to the DB.  I am trying to figure out how to use Envers to keep track of user modifications to the table (if they added something, deleted, or edited and the username of the user and the time at which it happened).  Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/appdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    <mapping
        resource="com/webapp/ui/database/Person.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/webapp/ui/database/Occupation.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/webapp/ui/database/Address.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/webapp/ui/database/Car.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping
        resource="com/webapp/ui/database/Education.hbm.xml" />

<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-insert"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-update"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-delete"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-update"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-remove"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-collection-recreate"/>   
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I also added the @Audited to the Bean classes.  After doing this it does not seem to work, the audit tables are not being created.

Comment: could you post your persistence.xml ?

Comment: @luuksen I do not have one, I let hibernate auto create everything.